# How can I loop through an IP address that is input by the user in python

Tags: python, unix, scripting, ip, range

Sorry i am new to python so I would like to inquire something. Let's say the user enter his IP ( 192.168.1.10 ), i want to start looping from his input (192.168.1.10) to the end of the sub net 192.168.1.255/24.

I was thinking something along this line

```
for i in range(256):
    IP = "192.168.1.%d" (i)
    print IP
```

But how do i put his input inside? Any guidance will be helpful, thanks.

Cheers,
Tech Newbie.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you, though I haven't tested it.

```
ip=raw_input("Enter an ip address:")
partToFetch= int(ip.split(".")[3])
for i in range(partToFetch,256):
    print "192.168.1.{0}".format(str(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you take the initial ip address with something like

```
IP = raw_input('Enter your IP:')
```

You can rework your loop

```
for i in range(256):
    print(IP[:IP.rfind('.')] + '.' + i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [**`ipaddress`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) module in Python 3.3. You can use an [index into a subnet as a list](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/ipaddress.html#networks-as-lists-of-addresses) of addresses:

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> subnet = ipaddress.ip_network('192.168.1.0/24')
>>> for i in range(10, 256):
>>>     print(subnet[i])
192.168.1.10
192.168.1.11
...
192.168.1.254
192.168.1.255
```